# How to determine if two IANA time zones are the same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

Given two different [IANA (aka "tz database" or "Olson") time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), how can I determine if they represent the same zone?

For example, `Asia/Kolkata` and `Asia/Calcutta` represent the same zone.

Another example, `Africa/Asmara` and `Africa/Asmera` represent the same zone.

These minor spelling differences matter when using APIs that [detect or guess the user's time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone/22625076#22625076), as one cannot then simply compare strings to a previously stored value, because different implementations return different variations of the time zone identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Modern JavaScript implementations that fully support the ECMAScript Internationalization API, can use the following:

```js
function areSameTimeZones(zone1, zone2) {
  var resolvedZone1 = Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeZone: zone1})
                          .resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  var resolvedZone2 = Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {timeZone: zone2})
                          .resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  return resolvedZone1 === resolvedZone2;
}
```

For applications requiring compatibility with older browsers, [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) can be leveraged:

```js
function areSameTimeZones(zone1, zone2) {
  var z1 = moment.tz.zone(zone1);
  var z2 = moment.tz.zone(zone2);
  return z1.abbrs === z2.abbrs && z1.untils === z2.untils && z1.offsets === z2.offsets;
}
```